# Try- except ValueError loop

Tags: python, try-catch

```
def enterNumber():
    number = input("Please enter a number to convert to binary. ")
    while True:
        try:
            int(number)
            convertDenary()
        except ValueError:
            enterNumber()
def convertDenary():
        binaryNumber = ['','','','','','','','']
        print(enterNumber())
        if enterNumber() > 128:
            enterNumber() - 128
            binaryNumber[0] == 1
enterNumber()
```

The `Try- Except ValueError` does loop as I intend it to however, it won't break. I've tried adding in `break` under the int(number), removing the `while True:` and added in the `convertDenary()` to see if it will force the subroutine to stop and start the other but it still doesn't work.

I get an infinite loop of "Please enter a number to convert to binary."
Any ideas?

Comment: just call `enterNumber` first thing in your `try` statement, and break after `convertDenary`. BTW your indentation is wrong.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Where's the indentation wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def convertToBinary(number):
   if number > 1:
       convertToBinary(number//2)
   elif number<1:
       enterNumber()

   print(number % 2,end = '')

def enterNumber():
    number = (input("Please enter a number to convert to binary : "))
    try:
        convertToBinary(int(number))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

enterNumber()
```

Comment: This works well however, how would I make this continuously loop until a valid input is entered?

Comment: @Joseph I edit the code. Hope your problem is solved!

Comment: How does the ConvertToBinary subroutine convert the denary to binary? I understand it takes the remaind of the modulo and prints it out but why does it not print out the 0s in front. For example 9 outputs 1001 but why doesn't it output 000010001?